# Create Columns on DataFrame with parsed list values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
OMDB_AWARDS OMDB_GENRE
1 Oscar     |Drama| 
2 Emmy      |Sci-Fi|Comedy|
1 Emmy      |Comedy|
```

How can I create dynamically the new columns as shown below?

```
OMDB_AWARDS OMDB_GENRE    OMDB_GENRE_DRAMA    OMDB_GENRE_Comedy    OMDB_GENRE_Sci-Fi    
1 Oscar     |Drama|                    1                    0            0
2 Emmy      |Sci-Fi|Comedy|            0                    1            1  
1 Emmy      |Comedy|                   0                    1            0
```

I can parse unique values in such way

> genre = pd.Series(df.OMDB_GENRE.ravel()).unique()

However still have issues with dynamic columns and appropriate values

Comment: Please post raw input data and code to reproduce your df exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way would be:

```
df['OMDB_GENRE_DRAMA'] = df.OMDB_GENRE.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'Drama' in x else 0)
```

and repeat for all genres. If you have many genres, you could take list of the genre names and do something like:

```
genres = ['Drama', 'Comedy', ..]
for genre in genres:
    df['OMDB_GENRE_{}'.format(genre)] = df.OMDB_GENRE.apply(lambda x: 1 if genre in x else 0)
```